# KeyError: 'Bytes_Written' python

Tags: python, json

I do not understand why I get this error Bytes_Written is in the dataset but why can't python find it? I am getting this information(see dataset below) from a VM, I want to select Bytes_Written and Bytes_Read and then subtract the previous values from current value and print a **json object** like this

```
{'Bytes_Written': previousValue-currentValue, 'Bytes_Read': previousValue-currentValue}
```

here is what the data looks like:

```
  {
      "Number of Devices": 2,
      "Block Devices": {
        "bdev0": {
          "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.26.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-d1c8e7c6-8c77-444c-9a93-8b56fa1e37f2-lun-010.0.0.142",
          "Capacity": "2147483648",
          "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
          "IO_Operations": "97069",
          "Bytes_Written": "34410496",
          "Bytes_Read": "363172864"
        },
        "bdev1": {
          "Backend_Device_Path": "/dev/disk/by-path/ip-192.168.26.1:3260-iscsi-iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-b27110f9-41ba-4bc6-b97c-b5dde23af1f9-lun-010.0.0.146",
          "Capacity": "2147483648",
          "Guest_Device_Name": "vdb",
          "IO_Operations": "93",
          "Bytes_Written": "0",
          "Bytes_Read": "380928"
        }
      }
    }
```

This is the complete code that I am running.

```
 FIELDS = ("Bytes_Written", "Bytes_Read", "IO_Operation")


def counterVolume_one(state):
    url = 'http://url'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    for field in FIELDS:
        state[field] += data[field]
    return state

state = {"Bytes_Written": 0, "Bytes_Read": 0, "IO_Operation": 0}
while True:
    counterVolume_one(state)
    time.sleep(1)
    for field in FIELDS:
        print("{field:s}: {count:d}".format(field=field, count=state[field]))

counterVolume_one(state)
```

Comment: `data['Block Devices'][field]` - your dictionary is inside another dictionary whose key is `Block Devices`.

Answer (score 1):

Your returned JSON structure does not have any of these `FIELDS = ("Bytes_Written", "Bytes_Read", "IO_Operation")` keys directly.

You'll need to modify your code slightly.

```
data = r.json()

for block_device in data['Block Devices'].iterkeys():
    for field in FIELDS:
        state[field] += int(data['Block Devices'][block_device][field])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this but it returns an error state[field] += data['Block Devices'][block_device][field]  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Updated the answer to include casting the block device field into an integer.